# Spring.net inject dictionary order question?

Tags: c#, dictionary, spring.net, inject

I use spring.net inject a `Dictionary<string,string>` in this order:

```xml
<object id="dictLang" type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string,string&gt;">
  <constructor-arg>
    <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="string" merge="0">
      <entry key="zh-CN" value="中文" />
      <entry key="en-US" value="英文" />
      <entry key="th-TH" value="泰文" />
    </dictionary>
  </constructor-arg>
</object>
```

When I use foreach to iterate it, it outputs this:

```
code=en-US,name=英文
code=th-TH,name=泰文
code=zh-CN,name=中文
```

I found it is ordered by the key,
how can I keep the order as I injected it?

When I create a dictionary manually:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic.Add("zh-CN", "中文");
            dic.Add("en-US", "英文");
            dic.Add("th-TH", "泰文");
```

It is the same order when I iterate it, that's weird!

I thought about using `OrderedDictionary`, but I don't know how to inject.

Answer (score 1):

Any "ordering" of [`Generic.Dictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is by [pfm](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pfm) and cannot be relied upon -- the fact that spring.net's injection leads to a slightly different key iteration order (perhaps one that *seems* to be sorted) is just luck and *cannot be relied upon*.

Notice that the injected dictionary [was passed an IDictionary itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz.aspx) as the constructor argument making it not identical to the manual code. Compare it with:

```
Dictionary<string, string> temp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
temp.Add("zh-CN", "中文");
temp.Add("en-US", "英文");
temp.Add("th-TH", "泰文");
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>(temp);
```

Even if the above doesn't yield the same key iteration order as that of spring.net, it is possible that there are other factors at play, such as a different [default capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk84bxf4.aspx) for "temp".

I cannot answer the "OrderedDictionary" part, however. (Most of the "specialized" collections are very underwhelming.)

Happy coding.