# Case Insensitive Dictionary with Spring.Net

Tags: c#, dictionary, spring.net

Is there a way create a dictionary in spring.net which case insensitive?

```
<dictionary key-type="string" value-type="string">
<entry key="abc">
<ref object="test"/>
</entry>
</dictionary>
```

Is there any way I can say that the dictionary key can be case insensitive. so that when I search for abc or ABC or Abc I will get the value of test?

Thanks

Added more entry

```
<object id="Test" type="string">
          <property name="Process">
<object id="ProcessDictionary" type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string, string&gt;, mscorlib">
                       <constructor-arg>
                              <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="string">
      <entry key="abc">
                                            <ref object="test"/>
                                     </entry>
                              </dictionary>
                       </constructor-arg>
                 </object>
          </property>
</object>
```

How do I add constructor parameter to ignore case sensitiveness ?

Comment: Not sure what is special with spring.net. I have no idea. But in general you do it [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609410/case-insensitive-string-for-use-in-dictionary)

Comment: Idea in the link will work if I instantiate the object myself, in this case spring.net will do that for me, so I'm trying to figure out how to set spring to use string.ignoreculturevariant flag during the object creation process

Comment: strange... I saw some one else posting a comment before mine and I dont see it now..

Comment: Nothing strange, he might have deleted the comment :)

Comment: That was me. But it was irrelevant due to Sriram's comment, so I removed it. Take a look here how to pass constructor arguments to spring.net: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370823/spring-net-inject-dictionary-order-question.

Comment: Updated the question, I still could not figure out how to add constructor parameter to ignore case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

After trying various spring configuration to make it working, finally I gave up and ended up using a private dictionary variable in the code and handled it through the private dictionary. I wish I could have found a way with spring itself

Comment: not really an answer. And not very clear what your issue was after you were given the links.